# How can put files in folder in django for settings

Tags: python, django

I have this folder structure for django

```
settings/dev.py
settings/prod.py
settings/test.py
```

Then i have common settings in settings/common.py in which i check the ENV variable like

```
if PROD:
   from settings.prod import *
```

Based on ENV variable each one of them will be active

I want to use something like this in my code

```
from myapp import settings
```

rather than

```
from myapp.settings import dev
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the method which I follow. Learnt this from the book Two Scoops of Django.

1. Have a file, such as, `settings/common.py` which will contain the properties/settings which are common in dev, prod and test environment. (You already have this.)
2. The other 3 files should:

   1. Import the common settings from the `settings/common.py` by adding the line `from .common import *`
   2. And should contain settings for its own corresponding environment.
3. The `manage.py` file decides which settings file to import depending on the OS environment variable, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. So, for test environment the value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should be `mysite.settings.test`

Links for reference:

1. Django documentation for `django-admin` utility - [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility)
2. Two Scoops of Django sample project - [Link](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name)

Answer (score 1):

Preserve your settings folder structure and create __init__.py there.

Please, use code below in your settings/__init__.py:

```
import os
# DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE
# if 1: Production Server
# else if 2: Test Server
# else: Development Server
server_type = os.getenv('DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE')

if server_type==1:
    from prod import *
elif server_type==2:
    from test import *
else:
    from dev import *
```

Now you can set environment variable called DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE to choose between Production, Test or Development Server and import settings using:

```
import settings
```

Comment: i am not sure why but i do that and i include   'from myapp import settings' then my test gices this error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_views'` this goes away if use normal settings file not folder

Comment: I mean in any test even if its empty , if i import that line then i get that error . if i remove that line then no error. but that work if i have settings.py in base dir and then all other files in settings/dev.py and then in settings.py in base dor i use whatever u have written in __init__.py